# Firebase Function for Rolling Counter

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

My Flutter app needs a *Rolling Counter* (1, 2, 3, ..., 98, 99, 1, 2, 3...).  Given that there may be multiple Flutter apps requesting and incrementing the *Rolling Counter*, I'm thinking that it makes sense to manage the counter using a *Cloud Function* (I generally use TypeScript).  (Note that I am also using *Cloud Firestore* and *Realtime Firebase*, if that helps.)

I can easily create a Google Cloud Function that uses something like `FieldValue.increment` to increment a counter.  The concern I have is over ***atomically* getting the value and then incrementing it** in a way that concurrency does not create a problem.  Strategies that limit the document read/write costs may also be attractive.

*What is a good strategy?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a firestore transaction, this will ensure that the data is correctly updated atomically. If the document is modified by another client the transaction will attempt to rerun a "finite amount of times".

See the documentation on transactions here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions

You can use transactions on the client-side or in a cloud function, depending on what best suits your needs. If you're only incrementing the value then a client-side function should work great, assuming you can properly secure the Firestore DB with necessary security rules.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  I was actually thinking this when I clicked submit, but I totally appreciate the second opinion.